# List Python Quantile

Tags: python, algorithm, list, quantile

I'm making a Quantile problems and I need to do something like this

Intervals:

```
150-155
155-160
160-165
165-170
170-175
175-180
180-185
```

---

```
>> inferior_limit = 150
>> superior_limit = 185
>> range = inferior_limit - superior_limit
>> number_of_intervals = 5
```

Those are the variables
and I need that because I'm doing a table's interval

```
>> width = range/number_of_intervals
>> while inferior_limit <= superior_limit
# there is my problem
>> inferior_limit += width
>> print inferior_limit
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you need help with.  Can you provide some details on what you've tried so far?

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry if I not clear but I speak english just a little bit because I french. My idea is only to do a list of intervals. Like the example

Comment: It would help a lot if you could specify what exactly the inputs and outputs are.

Comment: range(start, end, step)?

Comment: Avoid using the name `range` for your variables since it is a python builtin.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you meant?

```
>>> inf, sup, delta = 150, 185, 5
>>> print '\n'.join('{}-{}'.format(x, x + delta) for x in xrange(inf, sup, delta))
150-155
155-160
160-165
165-170
170-175
175-180
180-185
```

Comment: Thanks you men! I am beging with python and I do not know the join() funtion

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> start, stop, step = 150, 185, 5
>>> r = range(start, stop + 1, step) # You can use xrange on py 2 for greater efficiency
>>> for x, y in zip(r, r[1:]):
        print '{0}-{1}'.format(x, y)


150-155
155-160
160-165
165-170
170-175
175-180
180-185
```

A more efficient way of doing this is through the use of the `itertools` pairwise recipe.

```
from itertools import tee, izip
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)

for x, y in pairwise(r):
    print '{0}-{1}'.format(x, y)
```

Also just for fun here is a solution using `itertools.starmap`, since nobody ever uses it!

```
from itertools import starmap
print '\n'.join(starmap('{0}-{1}'.format, pairwise(r)))
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, and I have only one question instead of print, save the result on a variable or a list or dictionary, thats is possible?

Comment: like this: `mylist = ['{}-{}'.format(x, x + delta) for x in xrange(inf, sup, delta)]`

Comment: or using my method `['{0}-{1}'.format(x, y) for x, y in pairwise(r)]`